# Is importing one huge range with one equation or smaller ranges for specific columns preferable?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

With Google Sheets' `IMPORTRANGE` function, I've been importing a lot of data. Right now I'm importing almost the entire page with one `importrange` equation, but I'm wondering whether it would be less effort on the servers (forgive my terminology, I'm an amateur in this) to import specific ranges (scattered across the page) since I don't need the entire page, just maybe 3/4 of it.

I'm just worried whether the extra equations will offset any benefits from importing a smaller range?

My company runs their customer and orders management in Google Sheets. (At one point, I really hope they buy an actual accounting or CRM software, but I think that's incredibly unlikely at this point in time.)

The import range equation is open-ended, e.g.

```
IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/example", "CRM!F10:BJ")
```

Yes, I know this increases the load - and no, I can't define the load because our orders are increasing every month.

Comment: why the bother to fix something that isn't broken or disadvantage? Unless you like to share less information or worried about sealevel rising faster this way...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends. if you import every column of `F:BJ` range one-by-one it's not worth it. but if you just need 3/4 of it that's 14 columns less of data so it may be worth to replace your one-cell formula with multiple chunks.

one more option would be to use one more spreadsheet where you import those chunks and then from it, you will import all-in-one into your final spreadsheet